# The probability of photoluminescence

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Was reading about premeditated doping in semiconductors and the effect it imposes on the emission spectrum, doping as I read introduces defect states which are close to either the valence band edge or conduction band edge in which case the shift in the emission spectrum is not very conceivable but once deep defect states are introduced by doping, the PL spectrum sees a noticeable red shift, this I can understand but my question is shouldn't my PL spectrum for deep states be bi-modal (one transition from the conduction band edge to the defect state and the next from the defect to the valence band)instead of a simple mono modal red shift in the spectrum? Some research on the internet told me that in one of the shorter transitions, the energy is not released in form of a photon but a phonon, my question is what decides whether the transition is going to be radiative or non-radiative? I have worked a bit with Photoluminescence spectra of materials but never ended up seeing a bi-modal spectra that was created as a result of defect states, only of mixtures.